# sorting data in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-order-by, analytical

I have a tricky scenario.

Data in the table is as follows

```
CustomerId  Transaction Type    Transaction Amount
1               Payment          100
1               payment          200
1               ReversePayment  -100
1               ReversePayment  -200
```

I have transnational table with transaction types being "Payment", "ReversePayment". There are multiple records for a customer with some records being Payment and some being ReversePayment.

Is there a way to sort data as follows

```
CustomerId  Transaction Type    Transaction Amount
1               Payment              100
1               ReversePayment      -100
1               payment              200
1               ReversePayment      -200
```

If any one have a solution, please help.

Comment: You still didn't tell us what logic must be followed, to arrive at that ordering (regardless of whether or how that can be done in code). We can take a guess: you want to show "matching" payment and reverse payment together, on consecutive lines. Is that it? If so - will a reverse payment always match a payment (and, perhaps, there may be some "payments" that were not reversed, and you need those at the end? You need to clarify that too.) Is it not possible, for example, to have payments of 100 and 200, and a **single** reverse payment of -300?

Comment: If it's the latter, and you need to see what payment or payment**s** is or **are** reversed by a single ReversePayment, then (1) the problem no longer has a unique solution in general, and (2) the problem is much harder.

Comment: The logic is not clear. Voting to close.

Comment: Hi mathguy,yes you are correct. my requirement is to show "matching" payment and reverse payment together, on consecutive lines

Answer (score 2):

For this dataset, this should do it:

```
order by
    customerId,
    abs(transaction_amount),
    transaction_amount desc
```

This sort does not worry about the transaction type, but only about the amounts. The criteria on the absolute value of the amount ties records that have opposite values, then the next criteria puts the positive value first.

Comment: The OP still needs to fully explain the logic; but if it's to show each reverse payment under the payment it reverses, then your solution will not give the desired result - specifically when there are payments (and corresponding reversals) of equal amounts. For example: two payments of 100 and two reversals of -100. Your solution will show 100, 100, -100, -100, when in fact the desired result is 100, -100, 100, -100 (if in fact that's the desired result).

Comment: By the way, I see the answer already has (as I am writing this) two upvotes and one downvote. None of those is from me. The downvoter, in particular, has not explained their downvote.

Comment: @mathguy: agreed. I clearly mentionned that this works *for this dataset*. I understand what you say: for this to work, we would need an additional column that somehow defines the order (or the group) of payments... which is not showing in the sample data.

Comment: Or we can create our own such column, with ROW_NUMBER for example. But I won't speculate (much less write a solution) until the OP clarifies the requirement. No point in solving a problem the OP may not even have.

Comment: Hi GMB, your answer works perfectly for 90% of data. remaining 10% of data has identical amounts like belowCustomerId Transaction Type Transaction Amount
1    Payment    100
1    payment    100
1    ReversePayment  -100
1    ReversePayment  -100 i want output like CustomerId Transaction Type Transaction Amount
1    Payment     100
1    ReversePayment   -100
1    payment     100
1    ReversePayment   -100

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear, but my interpretation is that the OP wants to interleave the payments and reverses.  This suggests window functions:

```
order by customerid,
         abs(transactionamount),
         row_number() over (partition by customerid, transactiontype, abs(transactionamout) order by customerid),
         transactiontype asc
```