# Need to group records based on matching reversal in sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle, aggregate, row-number

I have a tricky scenario to aggregate the data.

Data in my source table is as follows.

```
CustomerId  Transaction Type    Transaction Amount
1               Payment              100
1               ReversePayment      -100
1               payment              100
1               ReversePayment      -100
1               Payment              100
1               Payment              100
```

Requirement is as follows:

- If the payment as a assoociated Reversepayment with matched amount, sum these two records.
- If the payment does not have an associated Reverse payment, consider it as orphan(dont sum it).

I want output to be like this.

```
  CustomerId    Transaction Type                Transaction Amount
   1                Payment,ReversePayment               0
   1                payment,ReversePayment               0
   1                payment                             100
   1               Payment                              100
```

In this scenario,

- First record which is payment has an associated reverse payment (2nd record), Hence the sum becomes 0
- Third record which is payment has an associated reverse payment (4th record), then the sum becomes 0
- Fifth and sixth does not have associated reversals. dont sum these records.

Second Example:

Data in the source as follows:

```
 CustomerId Transaction Type    Transaction Amount
 1              Payment              100
 1              ReversePayment      -100
 1              payment              300
 1              ReversePayment      -300
 1               Payment              400
 1               Payment              500
```

Expected Output

```
CustomerId      Transaction Type                Transaction Amount
 1              Payment,ReversePayment               0
 1              payment,ReversePayment               0
 1              payment                             400
 1              Payment                             500
```

Second example requirement: 
-As first and second records (payment and its associated reverse payment got 
 matched) ,sum these two records, output is 0.
- As third and fourth records (payment and its associated reverse payment got 
  matched), sum these two records, output is 0.
- Fifth and sixth does not have associated reversals. don't sum these records.

I got solutions in group, but data is not always guaranteed to have orphan records as 'payments'. Some times they are 'Payments' and some times they are 'ReversePayments'. Can some help me get ouptut like the below (using rank or rownumber functions ) so that i can group by using RRR column.

```
CustomerId  Transaction Type    Transaction Amount         RRR
 1              Payment              100                   1
 1              ReversePayment      -100                   1
 1              payment              100                   2
 1              ReversePayment      -100                   2
 1               Payment              100                   3
 1               Payment              100                   4


 CustomerId Transaction Type    Transaction Amount      RRR 
 1              Payment              100                 1
 1              ReversePayment      -100                 1
 1              payment              300                 2
 1              ReversePayment      -300                 2
 1               Payment              400                3
 1               Payment              500                4
```

Comment: Please indicate what's the primary key of the table.

Comment: "Fifth and sixth does not have associated reversals..." -- There's no such thing as "fifth" or "sixth" rows, since table rows do not have inherent ordering. Please clarify the question.

Comment: @The Impaler : Raised another post, please refer it. it will be more clear. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287312/need-to-group-records-based-on-matching-reversals

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate the different types and then aggregate:

```
select customerid,
       listagg(ttype, ',') within group (order by ttype) as types,
       sum(amount) as amount
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customerid, ttype, amount order by customerid) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by customerid, seqnum;
```

Comment: `partition by customerid, ttype, amount order by customerid` -- This doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Hi Gordon your solution worked fine my scenario, added one more example. need solution for that one also.

Comment: You should add ABS(amount) to the group by list so that different payment amounts don't get clubbed together as would happen with the OPs 2nd example.

Comment: @NazeerSyed . . . I answer questions as they are asked, not modified, enhanced questions.  Follow-ups should be a new question.

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . There is no column to specify the ordering and Oracle requires the `order by` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287312/need-to-group-records-based-on-matching-reversals

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Please help

Answer (score 1):

Edited to include your second scenario:

Using rownum to enforce inherent ordering (i.e. transactions happened in the order you've listed ), since your example is missing a transaction id or transaction time

```
    SQL> select * from trans_data2;

    CUSTOMER_ID TRANSACTION_TY TRANSACTION_AMOUNT
    ----------- -------------- ------------------
              1 Payment                       100
              1 ReversePayment               -100
              1 payment                       300
              1 ReversePayment               -300
              1 Payment                       400
              1 Payment                       500

    6 rows selected.


    SQL> select customer_id,
      2      case
      3          when upper(next_transaction) = 'REVERSEPAYMENT' then transaction_type||','||next_transaction
      4          else transaction_type
      5      end transaction_type,
      6      case
      7          when upper(next_transaction) = 'REVERSEPAYMENT' then transaction_amount + next_transaction_amount
      8          else transaction_amount
      9      end transaction_amount
     10  from (
     11      select customer_id, transaction_type, transaction_amount,
     12      lead (transaction_type) over ( partition by customer_id order by transaction_id ) next_transaction,
     13      nvl(lead (transaction_amount) over ( partition by customer_id order by transaction_id),0)  next_transaction_amount
     14      from ( select rownum transaction_id, t.* from trans_data2 t )
     15  ) where upper(transaction_type) = 'PAYMENT'
     16  ;

    CUSTOMER_ID TRANSACTION_TYPE              TRANSACTION_AMOUNT
    ----------- ----------------------------- ------------------
              1 Payment,ReversePayment                         0
              1 payment,ReversePayment                         0
              1 Payment                                      400
              1 Payment                                      500
```

Comment: Thanks vishnud, It worked for me as of now. Appreciate you help.

Comment: @NazeerSyed just noticed your second scenario, I've made edits to enforce inherent ordering, without which a lead() wouldn't guarantee consistent results

Comment: your first solution got worked for my two scenarios and second solution as well. i just ran your both of queries, got output as expected. Will let you and group know if i need help with any other scenario. Thanks a lot for your quick help.

Comment: Solution will work only when the orphan records are 'Payment'. Its not guarantee that orphan records are always 'Payments'. Some times they are 'Payments' and some times they are 'Reverse Payments' also. Can you give a soltuion using rownumber which gives result like 1,1,2,2,3,4. So that i can group based on row number.

Comment: @NazeerSyed not sure what you mean by orphan records, please clarify. The requirement to sort data is similar to what you're already asking on another thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60216700/sorting-data-in-oracle

Comment: Orphan records are the one's which does not have an associated reversal like the records of row number number 5,6 in my examples. As you applied filter where upper(transaction_type) = 'PAYMENT' , i am telling you that orphan records are not always 'PAYMENT', some times are 'REVERSEPAYMENT' also. Assume Record 6 is 'ReversePayment' in the example, then how the filtering condition is going to work? If you need i will share one more example as well.

Comment: @NazeerSyed sorry a bit confused when you say -  _"Orphan records are the one's which does not have an associated reversal"_ and _"orphan records are not always 'PAYMENT', some times are 'REVERSEPAYMENT' also"_  - logically, how could there be a reverse payment without an original payment record?

Comment: Raised another post, it should be more clear please refer, apprciate your help on this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287312/need-to-group-records-based-on-matching-reversals